# Implement AspNet Core Identity or Work account Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid

This is not like other questions you might find similar. My issue is way bigger.

**Scenario:**

I have 3 websites. All of them have a common database for authentication and stuff.

Problem is that i will need to expand to 2 more sites, which means more maintenance in login screens and so on. So i will dedicate time to make a "central website" to manage users, access, etc.

Also, Need to implement OpenId for Microsoft Works accounts (ie, Azure tenants).

**DDBB User Model:** (Simplified)

- All users are in the same central database. Which does not contains
  anything non-user related.
- User is personal on all applications.
- Users can have different Roles
- Each "User-Role" is mapped to an application, a server and a
  database.

**Problem:**

Created a site in AspNet Core, without any authentication done so I can do it myself since I found that mapping Aspnet Identity tables was no-go because of incopatibilities and overriding is way to complicated, specially when dealing with Managers.

So, Tried and got working a simple Authentication page using *HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync* and *CookieAuthentication*. Which works well and there is no need to use any of the Identity's implementation (which is not compatible with my backend).

But then I added UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication to have the OpenId auth, but I have no idea how to use it since its suposed to work out of the box when using Identity and when checked documentation they use this code in an controller action: *signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties* and I do not have any SignInManager since Im not using Aspnet Identity.

**Questions:**

1. Is coping the source of ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties to make it work in my site an aceptable solution?
2. Should I continue to override all SignInManager methods and also probably implement other classes to make Aspnet Identity work with my model?
3. Tried Mapping the properties to my columns just to test it out and it gave me non debuggable errors, which i dont like to even think about the problems this can give me in the future. For example one error was that it coudnt parse byte[] to string.
4. How can I implement Microsoft Work Accounts authentication and Database authentication in the same AspNet Site?

**Bonus topic**

Recently I feel like programming is becoming Configuring instead of coding. Is it just me? Are we now Professional Configurers?

Thanks

Comment: you might find my cloudscribe project interesting as it implements multi tenant identity and social auth https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe

Comment: Nice project, but it wont work for me. I dont need any of that, or any ORM, entity framework or anything.

Im checking passportjs and if it work i will just give up .Net for ever. Honestly im a bit tired of .Net and their aproach.

Another thing would be to do something like what you did, but modeled after my scenario, which gonna take me TOO LONG.